# Getting stats about a page on my site and links on that page from the Google API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a blog with the Google Analytics tag in the various pages. I also have links on my site pointing to pages on my site as well as external pages. I have not set up custom events or anything like that.

For a given url/page on my site, within a certain date range, I want to programatically get (ideally from the GA API):

1. Search words/traffic sources that unique users/traffic from outside my website (e.g. organic traffic searching on Google) used to land on and view that page
2. For specific links on that page - both internal and external - I want to know the number of unique users who clicked on the link and the number of clicks
3. For specific links on that page - both internal and external - I want to know the search terms/sources of the users/clicks of the links vs. the visitors that didn't click on the links

Is there a way I can fire a given link on my blog into the Google Analytics API to get this data? I already have a 2-column table that has all of the pages on my site (column 1) and all of the links/urls on those pages (column 2).

I am using Python for all of this btw.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: By get the search words do you mean - what user searches for on Google or your on your website search?

Comment: Thanks for question - I have tried to clarify in the question above

Comment: Got it and you want to extract this data programmatically from GA API right?

Comment: Yep that would be ideal - I just clarified the question again into 3 points to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the information you're looking for:

1. **You won't get organic keywords via the GA API**: what you will get most of the time is `(not provided)` ([here is some info and workarounds](https://neilpatel.com/blog/unlock-keyword-not-provided/)). You can get this data in the GA UI by [linking the search console](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1308621?hl=en), but that data won't be exposed via the GA API, only the [Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/) (formerly "webmasters"), which unfortunately you won't be able to link with your GA data.
2. **You will need to implement custom events** if you want to track link clicks, as by default GA doesn't do it ([here is an example](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en) which you can use for both internal and external links). Once you have the events implemented, you can use the [`ga:eventAction`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=event_tracking&jump=ga_eventaction) or [`ga:eventLabel`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=event_tracking&jump=ga_eventlabel) to filter on your links (depending on how you implemented the events), and [`ga:totalEvents`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=event_tracking&jump=ga_totalevents) / [`ga:uniqueEvents`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=event_tracking&jump=ga_uniqueevents) to get the total / unique number of clicks.
3. **You will need to create [segments](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en)** in order to define conditions about what users did or did not do. What I advise you to do is to create and test your segments via the UI to make sure they're correct, then simply [refer to the segments via ID using the API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration#segments).

As for the GA API implementation, before coding I advise you to get familiar with the API using:

- [The query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)
- [Google Sheets + GA API plugin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on)

Once you get the results you're looking for, you can automate with the [Google Python Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) (it's the same client for (nearly) all Google APIs), GA being a service you use with the client, and you'll find some [python samples here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples).